# update markercluster after removing markers from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am currently using markercluster plugin with jquery ui maps.

I have two arrays one of all markers (called markers) and one of markers that match search criteria (called current_markers). These are fitered from the first array.

I then draw the current_markers on screen.

I am finding however that the markerclusterer library is not updating based on this change.

So how can I update the markerclusterer?

Is it possible to assign the markerclusterer to a variable and call an update function?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should store the marker object in a var and then unset the map as following:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
/// ... later on
markerCluster.setMap(null);
```

after you've done this, you could init a `new MarkerClusterer` with new markers

**Update**

since you are using google maps ui plugin here's some additional code. I've added a click even on a button with class `reset_markercluster` ofcourse this is just to show how to use it to call the map

```
var _map, _markerCluster;

$(function() {
  $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(event, map) { 
    _map = map; // at this point you can call _map whenever you need to call the map

    // build up your markers here ...

    _markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(_map, markers);  // you could also use map instead of _map here cause it's still present in this function
  });

  $("button.reset_markercluster").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _markerCluster.setMap(null);  // remove's the previous added markerCluster

    // rebuild you markers here ...

    _markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(_map, newMarkers);

  });
});
```

Comment: within the constructor `map, markers` or you also could set it with the `setMap()`

Comment: ok so in which case how do I set the map to a variable? I'm mostly getting confused because of the jquery ui map plugin.

Comment: I am getting an error saying 'object has no method of draggable'

Comment: this plugin: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html

Comment: Ok the same as me then. Is there a way when cycling the markers in the _clusterer to find if the marker has been clustered or not?

Comment: mind this is actually another question, anyway please read the javascript. It contains a method `getMarkers()` returning the added markers to the cluster. You could check this array with the marker to figure out if it's present

Comment: Good point about deviation from the original question. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 65):

Yes you can.

### Creating the map

Assuming you have created your MarkerClusterer object something like this:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 20);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 6, center: center, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });
var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map);
```

### Adding markers

You can add multiple markers to it something like this:

```
var markers = []
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: center});
markers.push(marker);
markerClusterer.addMarkers(markers);
```

Note that here I have added only one.

### Removing all markers

You can then clear all the markers using clearMarkers something like this:

```
markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
markers = [];
```

Note that for tidiness I have also unset the markers array here.

### Docs

Full documentation on all the available methods is available here:

<s>https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html</s>

UPDATED Link: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclustererplus/classes/markerclusterer.html#clearmarkers

It's a sensible and relatively complete API.

Comment: excellent answer as you not only addressed the OP, but also showed the full process related to marker management independent of clusterer construction

Comment: Thanks @hubsonbropa, nice of you to say.

Comment: Link is dead, its very confusing to find up-to-date info, this definitly helps!

Comment: Thanks. markerClusterer.clearMarkers(); is the better option.

Answer (score 12):

It's best to use the clearMarkers() method from your markerCluster object:

<s>http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html</s>
updated reference: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclustererplus/classes/markerclusterer.html#clearmarkers

Comment: updated link: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclustererplus/classes/markerclusterer.html#clearmarkers

Answer (score 2):

[marker-clusterer-plus](https://github.com/mikesaidani/marker-clusterer-plus) has a `removeMarkers` method:

```
markerCluster.removeMarkers(markers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manage like this.

1. Create blank cluster variable

   ```
   var _markerCluster;
   ```
2. Store cluster object on our variable.

   _markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
   imagePath:    'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
   });

3. When you remove marker then you have need to write bellow code.

```
    try{
         _markerCluster.clearMarkers();
    }catch(e){
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent update, Into your html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

Into your JS

```
var mc = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ markers, map });
```

Removing markers and clusters

```
function clearOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers=[];
  mc.clearMarkers();
}
```